# Add new entry to the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters

I have the next problem:

I am doing the final degree project and my school forces me to make chapters with a special pdf. The point is that I have added this pdf and it appears properly, but I still have the other page where the chapter appears `\chapter{Chapter_1}`. Now what I want is to delete this page but make it appear in the Table of Contents.

I do not know if it can be done just deleting the `\chapter` command and adding in some way to ToC or in any other way. I am sorry if this question is already done, but I have not been able to find it.

Comment: are you using `pdfpages` package? or better can  you show us how the pdfs are included?

Comment: The two relevant commands might be `\addcontentsline { ext }{ unit }{ text }` and `\addtocontents { ext }{ text }` (where `ext` would be `toc` and `unit` would be `chapter`) ... but it's really hard to say since you've provided no code for us to examine. Please edit your question to include a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Answer (score 3):

as [jon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8528/jon) said it : you can use `\addcontentsline` :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{TEST1}
\section{sec11}
\section{sec12}
\section{sec13}
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\thechapter\hspace{2ex}TEST2}
\chapter{TEST3}
\section{sec31}
\section{sec32}
\section{sec33}
\end{document}
```

Using `2ex` is not the best way ; I think you must use the `titlesec` package to be sure that it is the right spacing.

[image]